# How do I set a downloadable file after purchasing a product on my Webiste? WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

thanks to whoever takes from their time to answer my question!

So basically I have a WooCommerce Webiste and I need to add a function in the function.php of my WordPress.
What it needs to do?

Let's say you purchase a product from my website that is 'Assessments' and I want you to download the Assessment done (when is done) from your Downloads tab on your profile, what is important for me is that I can upload the file by checking if the user is '1' and has the order number '1', or it just checks if the order number is on his profile.

I have been looking around the web trying to find a solution for this but nothing at the moment, I got a snippet that adds a Download in the Download section, but it adds it for everyone, I want it to be specific for the order number o the user id or both.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not totally sure I fully understand your question, but to me it looks like you've set the product type to a "physical product"? Digital products should automatically be added to the customer's downloads after purchase. A link to the file should also be included in the order summary a user sees after their payment has been processed.

Otherwise I assume this is an issue in your template. Which one are you using?

Comment: I am using Astra as a template, I thought of doing it with the Digital Products as well but the problem is, being a file that won't be ready at the purchase, instead will be ready after couple of days and it will be different for every customer, I was wondering on how could I do that? Like adding in their download tab the file once it's ready! Thanks for your answer btw!

Comment: Ah, I see. In that case you'll most likely require quite a lot of customisation throughout both WooCommerce and your theme.

While I haven't build a project like this before, I think I do have two relatively simple solutions for your issue:

1. Simply restyle your "order notes" to deliver your products when ready. These may include links, so you can even have your users download the files from a different server. Links/files aren't protected using this approach.
2. Add a hidden digital product that includes variations. Whenever a file is ready, you can add a variation for the customer..

Comment: Part 2/2:
.. then create a new order for the customer, include the variation and complete.

Please note that while option 2 is functionally better, it's really hacky/non-scalable/technically crappy.